# Удалить повторяющиеся элементы списка SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Помогите реализовать на swi-prolog алгоритм, решающий следующую задачу:
Необходимо удалить все повторяющиеся элементы в списке. Например дан список: [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], после обработки получаем список [1,2,3,4].

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
remove_duplicates([], []):-!.
remove_duplicates([X|Xs], Ys):-
      member(X, Xs),
      !, remove_duplicates(Xs, Ys).
remove_duplicates([X|Xs], [X|Ys]):-
%     \+ member(X, Xs),
      !, remove_duplicates(Xs, Ys).
```

- первое предложение - условие завершения рекурсии.
- второе предложение - проверка первого элемента на принадлежность
  списку и просмотр остатка списка
- третье предложение -  просмотр остатка списка